# Centering the text of a vertical header in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` with the vertical header visible. By default, this header is numbered. I cannot figure out how to center the text (numbers), though. Here's what it looks like now (the red parts are the headers):

[image]

Here is the code I currently have. I tried applying an alignment property with CSS, but it doesn't work. Everything else seems to work via CSS (coloring), but not the text alignment.

```
ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QHeaderView::section{background-color: #e5cbcb; text-align: center;}"));
```

How can I center the numbers?

Comment: Have you tried `ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setDefaultAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);` ?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked! If you want to submit that as an answer, I will mark it as complete. Thank you!

Comment: Just posted. You are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [setDefaultAlignment()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#defaultAlignment-prop)

With these flags:

```
Qt::AlignLeft   0x0001  Aligns with the left edge.
Qt::AlignRight  0x0002  Aligns with the right edge.
Qt::AlignHCenter    0x0004  Centers horizontally in the available space.
Qt::AlignJustify    0x0008  Justifies the text in the available space.
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way using only style sheet is:

```
setStyleSheet("QHeaderView { qproperty-defaultAlignment: AlignHCenter; }");
```

See section [Setting QObject Properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) in Qt documentation.